# phonegapFacebookConnectPlugin does not exist in iOS

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins

CDVPlugin class FacebookConnectPlugin (pluginName: FacebookConnectPlugin) does not exist.
2014-12-03 16:12:11.472 crossfit[26380:613] ERROR: Plugin 'FacebookConnectPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

Comment: i found my solution                                                       in XCode, goto Build Phases -> open the Compiled Sources dropdown. Click + and add the missing plugin .m file that should be in your Plugins directory (but is missing from the compiled sources).

Answer (score 0):

i found my solution

in XCode, goto Build Phases -> open the Compiled Sources dropdown. Click + and add the missing plugin .m file that should be in your Plugins directory (but is missing from the compiled sources)